# .NET 8.0 WebAPI project docker is running on the docker desktop but it I cannot send request

Tags: .net

I am trying to send a request to a docker container with specified port 5687->8080 and 5688->8081. But it is always returning "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". However when I try to debug it from Visual Studio with Docker selection I can send the same request and it is working. It seems I am missing a small nuance but could not find it still, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.